# Accessing another programs memory location through pointer

Tags: windows, pointers, memory-management

Is It possible to access a memory location which is used by another program of windows or other utility by using pointer.

Comment: Only by attaching as a debugger

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx).